# How can I choose where chrome notifications pop up?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, notifications

I am running Chrome on Windows 8.1  When I get new notifications, they pop up somewhere in the middle of the screen, instead of in the bottom corner.  This is really annoying, as I can't remove them without clicking on them (and performing whatever action that results from such a click), and I can't move them.  I have to wait until they disappear.

Previously the notifications would pop up on the bottom right corner would disappear, but not that seems to have changed.

I don't see any setting that controls where notifications pop up.  Is there any way to control this?